# Translating "You have no right to kill people even if you are hungry." into German

Tags: translation, english-to-german

How can you translate

> You have no right to kill people even if you are hungry.

into German?

My attempt is:

> Du hast kein Recht zu töten Menschen selbst wenn du bist hungrig.

Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say:

> Du hast kein Recht Menschen zu töten, selbst wenn du hungrig bist.